# Conditional alternating Parent tags in jsx

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

Use Case:

```
array.map((field, index) =>{
  const Wrapper = index % 2 === 0 ? <RowWrapper> : <React.Fragment>
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Col md={4}>
      </Col>
      <Col md={2}>
      </Col>
    </Wrapper>
  );
})
```

Expected Output:

```
<RowWrapper>
  <Col md={4}>
  </Col>
  <Col md={2}>
  </Col>
  <Col md={4}>
  </Col>
  <Col md={2}>
  </Col>
</RowWrapper>
```

In the above scenario. Basically I want map to return an opening `RowWrapper` tag but not closing tag until I have mapped two fields.

Comment: You changed your expected output after I answered; the new expected output code doesn't exactly match the text as you have described it-- could you clarify?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I need two 2 bootstrap columns for each `field` item. One for input and one for pop up button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe that JSX can be made to behave in exactly this manner, in which closing tags are conditionally rendered.  However, the output is still achievable if you get clever with your `map` callback:

```js
array.map((field, index) =>{
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return (
        <RowWrapper>
          <Col md={6}>current content is {array[index]}</Col>
          <Col md={6}>next index content is {array[index+1]}</Col>
        </RowWrapper>
      );
  }
  return null; // just skip if this isn't an even numbered index
})
```

I haven't tested that but something like that should accomplish the output you desire.  Obviously you'd want to add checking for off-by-one type scenarios.